# Save Settings in VB.Net or C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

How I can save the settings I want even after I close the program?

Let's say: If I have a `Checkbox` and I run the program. If I checked it I want to remain that way even when I reopen again the program. I hope you understand what I want.

I'm a newbie, so take me slow. Thank you.

Comment: 1. If this is Visual Basic, you tagged the question with C#, not VB. 2) You have to persist the result of that checkbox somewhere. A database, or a config file, or the registry are all normal places that can be used. You need to decide which route to pursue based on your software design. There should be plenty of tutorials resulting from a Google search.

Comment: @mrunion, +1, that's a legitimate answer. You may consider posting it as answer though with little more info.

Comment: However saving configuration options into the Registry should be avoided

Answer (score 10):

I recommend using [Application Settings Property Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/wabtadw6(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

There are many options as mrunion mentioned in his good answer, but I think the most simple way in Windows Forms Application is using Application Settings Property Binding. To do so using designer:

1. Select your `CheckBox` in design surface
2. In properties window, at top, expand `(ApplicationSettings)`, open dropdown for `Checked` property and select `(New...)` at bottom of dropdown.
3. Add your desired property with default value.
4. Save settings in somewhere like `Form_Closing` event:

   - C#: `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`
   - VB: `My.Settings.Save()`

**(ApplicationSettings) in property window:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Expanded from above....

To persist settings between different program runs, you will have to store that data somewhere for the user. Assuming since you mentioned VB, I will also assume Windows as your target platform. The best options are the following:

1. Use the registry to store the persistent data. There are plenty of tutorials on setting and retrieving registry variables.
2. Use a configuration/INI file for your application. Again, plenty of tutorials exist for this option.
3. Use a database. This is more advanced, but allows for the most flexibility of storing and retrieving data. I would suggest not using this method at first, and revisit it when you are ready to learn database design/querying/etc.

This should point you in the right direction.