# Excel/ OpenFileDialog: Save to string last browsed file even after application exit

Tags: c#, excel, openfiledialog

I'm almost finished with my program, the only thing left missing is when I don't have to browse my excel file all over again. It's either I'll code it but can never change it or OpenFileDialog again and again everytime I run the program.

Is there a way to save the file location to string after browsing for the file even after application exit? So I won't have to browse for the file again and if ever the file is moved or missing, I can browse for the file only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can use `Setting` file as following:

1. Add a setting file to your project.
2. Add a property to your setting file.
3. Set the value of this property when you need `Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty="path"`
4. Get the value of this property when you need `Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty`
5. Save settings when form closing

Save settings when formclosing:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The settings loads automatically and you don't need load settings at startup.

Comment: So many things I still don't know about Visual Studio. I was hoping that the answer would be about OpenFileDialog or something. But this works totally fine. Thanks

Comment: @JoeyLorenzoPascual You are welcome:) This approach may be useful for many other situations in the future. You may wnat to take a look at this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/32487895/3110834  I'll be happy if you find it helpful. In that answer I offer using designer to perform settings for a checkbox to preserve value of it.