# WinForms c# Saving checkbox status and then reading it back once the program is opened again

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, visual-studio-2015

I am making a program that is composed of mostly just Check Boxes. I want to save the checkbox status before the program is closed, and then have the program set the checkbox status as it last was.

I have looked at several questions and answer about this, and I have tried them all. Most of them are pretty old and are using VisualStudio 2010. I have tried using Property Settings, and I have also tried to make a file and then read off of that file and set the CheckBox status to whatever it last was.

I am pretty new to C# so I must be doing something wrong, I would appreciate any help that you guys could give me. Thank you.

Comment: [Save Settings in VB.Net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487574/save-settings-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could follow the tutorial from the link below. This handles exactly your requirements.

[tutorial for saving user settings](http://www.sorrowman.org/c-sharp-programmer/save-user-settings.html)

So basically what you have to do is to create foreach check box a setting like below one in Settings of your project.

[image: check box seeting]

Then select your check box from designer and from Properties tab choose Application settings and Property binding then Checked and then "checkBox1State".

So the check box checked status is mapped to "checkBox1State" application setting.

Then you have just to save the settings when closing the form.

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

For tracking more check boxes just repeat these steps.

Comment: Take a look at [Save Settings in VB.Net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487574/save-settings-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp) You don't need to assign values to settings manually. You can use data-binding to application settings. It seems the question is an exact duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you for remarks ! I updated the response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I added a button that did the "Properties.Settings.Default.Save()" process and it works perfectly fine. Again, thank you.

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.checkstate = true;` <-- how to set the Properties.