# How can I save and load the last selected folder by user with FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The LastSelectedFolder not exist.
I tried to go to the project properties to the Settings tab and there i added to the value the LastSelectedFolder.

So now I have: Name Setting Type string Scope user Value LastSelectedFolder

But it's not working still getting the error and also after saving where and how do I load it back when clicking the btnStart?

The LastSelectedFolder is not exist after the Default even after added it to the Settings:

[image: Settings]

Comment: You saved the last selected folder, but next time which you show the `FolderBrowserDialog` you didn't use it.

Comment: **1)** In your new edition of the question, we can see in the screenshot, the property is named `Setting` containing the value `LastSelectedFolder`. So your code currently should have build error because you use `Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder`. **2)** Also you don't need to assign the setting to the property of folder browser manually, use Property Binding to Application settings like this: [Save Settings in VB.Net or C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32487574/3110834)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the last path as default if you create a new dialog. Therefore you can use also the `FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath` property. Here is your code with the additional line:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    openFolderDialog.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder;

    if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
            Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

In your screenshot you named your setting `Setting`. Change this one to `LastSelectedFolder` and clear the default value (last column).

After that you can compile and run!

Comment: But LastSelectedFolder is not exist after the Default: Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder even after added the LastSelectedFolder to the Settings in the project properties.

Comment: This sounds like a problem of the settings. Can you show the settings?

Comment: I added the solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        openFolderDialog.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder;

        if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```