# Make FileDialogs start from given directory but then from last used

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I have a form that has an `OpenFileDialog` and a `SaveFileDialog` declared at class scope:

```
    private OpenFileDialog OpenDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Title = "Open",
        AddExtension = true,
        DefaultExt = "json",
        Filter = "JSON Files (*.json)|*.json",
        CheckFileExists = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,
        DereferenceLinks = true,
        Multiselect = false,
        ShowReadOnly = false,
        ValidateNames = true,
        RestoreDirectory = false
    };

    SaveFileDialog SaveDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
    {
        Title = "Save",
        AddExtension = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,
        CreatePrompt = false,
        DefaultExt = "json",
        Filter = "JSON Files (*.json)|*.json",
        RestoreDirectory = false
    };
```

They are then used in a event handlers like so:

```
    private void openToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OpenDialog.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //...
```

I would like to set these so that the first time a user opens the application the directory that the dialogs open at is a predemined one. Thereafter however, should the user open the dialogs again they should open to whatever directory the user last used them at.

I have been dickering around with the `RestoreDirectory` and `InitialDirectory` properties in the main form's `Load` event but have not been able to achieve this. Is this possible using the Dialogs' standard properties or methods?

Comment: As far as i know Windows does this automatically if you don't specify an InitialDirectory.

Comment: @yanyankelevich If I don't set the `InitialDirectory` then it doesn't fulfil "the directory that the dialogs open at is a predemined one"

Comment: FileDialog.RestoreDirectory=true;  the dialog box restores the directory to the previously selected directory before closing. InitialDirectory - uses for first loading directory.

Comment: @MuradGaribzada Yep, tried that - doesn't work. Ta

Comment: You can use `Settings.settings`.  Take a look at [Save Settings in VB.Net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487574/save-settings-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you will need to persist this information, e.g. in the Windows registry.  This would be an example of a user setting, i.e. one that is stored separately for each user who logs onto the machine.  The first time the dialog is open, the setting would be absent and thus would default to your initial directory; then, you store the chosen value and use that for subsequent dialogs.

Comment: Is it a user setting even though it doesn't persist through application restart? - kinda thought this might be the answer though

Comment: So you don't want it to persist through application restart?  You can clear the user setting upon loading the application.