# How to save to settings a checkBox state?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void checkBoxSaveRectangles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxSaveRectangles;          
    }
```

I tried:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxSaveRectangles = checkBoxSaveRectangles.CheckState;
```

but CheckState is not bool.

CheckBoxSaveRectangles in the Settings is type bool.

I want to save the checkBoxSaveRectangles state and load the state in the constructor and to update a global bool in the constructor and in the CheckedChanged event.

or maybe there is no need for a global bool flag variable just to check where I need the checkBoxSaveRectangles state?

because I want to save the state and also to make some stuff depending on the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the state of a `checkBoxSaveRectangles` in the settings, you can use the [`Checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked) property which is a `bool` type. Note that you should use `Save` method to [save settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp):

```
private void checkBoxSaveRectangles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxSaveRectangles = checkBoxSaveRectangles.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Next you can set the state of the `CheckBox` from the application settings. You can [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-read-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp) the `CheckBoxSaveRectangles` value from the `Properties.Settings` in the constructor of the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    checkBoxSaveRectangles.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxSaveRectangles;
}
```

Also you can read this value from settings in any place of your code if needed.

Comment: Or you may want to use property binding to settings; the following post shows you the right way of binding the CheckBox.Checked property to a setting: [Save Settings in VB.Net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487895/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understand the question but maybe the problem is that you forget to save the setting. Try adding this line:

`Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`;